# How can I let my code send messages simultaneously?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm trying to do UDP socket programming in Python, and I want both the client and the server to be able to send messages without the need to wait for the other party to send a message first.

Here is my server code:

```
import socket

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1',12345))

while True:
    data,addr=sock.recvfrom(4096) #byte size 
    print("Client says: ")
    print(str(data))
    message = bytes(input("Enter message here: ").encode('utf_8'))
    sock.sendto(message,addr)
```

and here is my client code:

```
import socket

client_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    msg=input("Enter your message here: ")
    client_socket.sendto(msg.encode('utf_8'),('127.0.0.1',12345))
    data,addr=client_socket.recvfrom(4096) #byte size  
    print("Server says")  
    print(data)
```

What should I edit in my code to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two functions to handle listening and sending.
Then you start them as threads so they run in parallel.
Each function has its own loop. The receive thread waits for messages and the send thread waits for user input

```
def client_receive():
  while True:
    data,addr=client_socket.recvfrom(4096) #byte size  
    print("Server says")  
    print(data)

def send_chat_message():
  while True:
    msg=input("Enter your message here: ")
    client_socket.sendto(msg.encode('utf_8'),('127.0.0.1',12345))

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_receive)
receive_thread.start()

send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_chat_message)
send_thread.start()
```

The above code will not really work at this point. But there are good tutorials out there. Search for **python socket chat threaded tutorial**

Often they are not based on a server handling inputs, but multiple clients connecting to a server. If you understand the concept, you'll have no problem adjusting the server to allow inputs there aswell.

Comment: Another option is to simply use non-blocking sockets, then no threads are needed. Use `select()` or selectors to handle asynchronous reading without blocking the rest of the code.

Comment: As I work with windows as my primary OS and in relation to this [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) I never bothered with non-blocking sockets, mostly because of the remark at the bottom of the page: **In fact, on Windows I usually use threads (which work very, very well) with my sockets.**